# Debugging Blender on VSCode

Tags: versions

I am trying to debug blender via gdb on Visual Studio Code. I have a launch.json file and it will open up blender but immediately close. I am not sure what is going on, has anyone successfully . Here is my json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch Blender",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "path/to/bin/Debug/blender.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "path/to/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "Build Blender Debugger"
    }
]
```

}

It seems to build but when it launches Blender it immediately closes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue is using gdb ... When I changed the debugger to be used cppvsdgp I was able to get it to launch and debug.